# Issue with self.navigationController and pushViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am having trouble pushing from a tableview to a detail view. When I click the tableview cell, the cell highlights but does not push to the detail view. I am using this to transition to the detail view:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

I have read that this is a common issue, but am somehow unable to figure out a solution. My full .m file is below. If anyone has any recommendations that would be amazing. Thank you!

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"title";

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/json.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
[mainTableView reloadData];
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [news count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
}

cell.textLabel.text = textForMyLabel;
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];

[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];

DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.title = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
detailViewController.newsArticle = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Does your viewController is within `UINavigationController` itself?

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas, I don't think so, Im not too sure how to check. I am trying to integrate two projects and don't know exactly what to look at.

Comment: you need to first have a navigation controller allocated with a rootviewcontroller. Then you can only push other views.

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas where would I allocate a navigation controller with a rootviewcontroller? In the app delegate.m file?

Comment: That's as per your requirement. You can put in delegate.m. But the point is your viewcontroller should already be in the stack. If not it cannot push other viewcontroller to the stack.

Comment: Its a bit complicated a project because I am loading it in a tab bar

Comment: then you have do something more..After allocating the UINavigationController you have to pass it to the array of Viewcontrollers of tab bar using the property 'viewControllers'.

Please follow the link.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers

Answer (score 0):

you try:

```
[self presentModalViewController: detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: That is an interesting way to do it, but I would like to have it transition like a normal detail view

Answer (score 0):

You can perform push oly with a UINavigationController, the above code will work if your Controller is UINavigationController. Since your trying to integrate two projects just check whether the RootViewController is a UINavigationController.

Comment: Would I look in the app delegate to find what the RootViewController is?